# In sqlalchemy, how to check if a model is attached on session?

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

In sqlalchemy, how to check if one object of model is attached on session?
and how to get attached session of one model object.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Session is not attached with any model, but rather it is attached to the object of the model. You will get the attached session from the object with the help of [`object_session`](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/13/orm/session_api.html#sqlalchemy.orm.session.object_session) method.

Answer (score 13):

To answer the first question if an object is attached to a session, you can use:

```
print(obj in DBSession)
```

Or use [inspect](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/core/inspection.html#sqlalchemy.inspection.inspect):

```
from sqlalchemy import inspect
print(not inspect(obj).detached)
```

See also: http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/orm/session_state_management.html#getting-the-current-state-of-an-object